# how to get just the value of a list in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [float]
```

My requirement is to just get the value of the 'a' list in 'b', i.e.

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5, float]
```

So, if we either append of insert, that will again create list of list, which I don't want.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
a.__add__(b)
```

output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, <class 'float'>]

Answer (score 3):

Assume your input is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ['float']

b{:] = a+b

print (b)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'float']
```

If your input is:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [float]
```

then your output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, <class 'float'>]
```

Answer (score 2):

this may be a bit clumsy, but it does what you want:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ["float"]

print(id(b))

for n in reversed(a):
    b.insert(0, n)
    
print(b)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'float']
print(id(b))
```

note that the `id` does not change - no new list is created.

slice-assignment would also work:

```
b0 = b[0]
b[:len(a)] = a
b.append(b0)
```

---

if you don't mind working with a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of a `list` you could also do this:

```
from collections import deque

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = deque(["float"])

b.extendleft(reversed(a))   # deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'float'])
```

Comment: cant you just do b=a+b to get the result?  I dont recommend a lot of code to do this.

Comment: @JoeFerndz no, that would create a new list which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: `b[::] = a+b` will retain the id.   `>>> a = [1,2,3,4]`
`>>> b = ['float']`
`>>> id(a)`
`140368030961024`
`>>> id(b)`
`140368030374656`
`>>> b[::] = a+b`
`>>> id(b)`
`140368030374656`
`>>> b`
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 'float']`

Comment: @JoeFerndz `b[:]` would do. clever! +1